# What if all the authors in my paper are from the same institute?

Tags: tables, elsarticle, author

Below is my code; how do I modify it so that the *a* is not shown in the figure below? Because all of the authors are from the same institute, there is no need to use an alphabet as a quote.

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=black
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}

\title{xx}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

\author{A\textsuperscript{\Letter}}
\author{B}
\author{C}
\author{D}
\author{E}
\affiliation[inst1]{organization={xx},
            city={yy},
            state={zz},
            postcode={1}, 
            country={2}}

\begin{abstract}
xx

\end{abstract}
\begin{keyword}

\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\blank}  \footnote{{\Letter} {Corresponding author, Email address: \linkable{}}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is too much code; could you reduce it down further please? It helps people answer quicker too when there is only a few packages loaded, you have around 30 loaded. Please check out [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), it helps everyone including yourself if it is reduced :)

Comment: thanks a lot for the comment, updated

Comment: Thank you, +1 for the update :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't advise it, but you could redefine `\theaffn`.  Elsevier might prefer a whole bunch of `Ibid`s instead.

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=black
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}

\title{xx}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

\author{A}
\author{B}
\author{C}
\author{D}
\author{E}

\let\theaffn=\relax
\affiliation{organization={xx},
            city={yy},
            state={zz},
            postcode={1}, 
            country={2}}
\begin{abstract}
xx

\end{abstract}
\begin{keyword}

\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}
%\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\blank}  \footnote{{\Letter} {Corresponding author, Email address: \linkable{}}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! What do you mean by Ibid?

Comment: Skort for "Ibidem" or "In the same place."  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibid.